# How to send an int from arduino to c# on pc

Tags: c#, bluetooth, int, arduino-uno

I am attempting to design a program in C# that communicates with an Arduino board. This program should receive integer data from the Arduino and display something related to the value.

The only thing i need is a code in C# and Arduino Uno in order to send a value (int) from arduino to c# on pc (laptop integrated Bluetooth).

Ask me if you need the code of my program.

I've done the program on C# , let me know if it's correct.

```
using System;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;

public class travauxEncadre
{
static public void Main()
{

    string data = "0";
    int Consommer = int.Parse(data);

    //Début Prise des valeurs manuelle

    Console.Clear();


    //Définition du seuil d'avertissement

    Console.WriteLine("Seuil d'avertissement");
    string SeuilAvertissement = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Clear();


    // Définition du seuil d'exces

    Console.WriteLine("Seuil d'exces");
    string SeuilExces = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Clear();


    //Défintion de la conso actuelle (a enlever)

    //  Console.WriteLine("Consommation");   
    //  string Conso = Console.ReadLine();
    //  Console.Clear();



    int Avertissement = int.Parse(SeuilAvertissement);
    int Exces = int.Parse(SeuilExces);
    //  int Consommer = int.Parse(Conso);

    //Fin Prise des valeurs manuelle



    //Début Bluetooth

    SerialPort port;

    port = new SerialPort();

    port.BaudRate = 9600;
    port.DataBits = 8;
    port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    port.Parity = Parity.None;

    port.PortName = "COM4";

    port.DataReceived += Port_DataReceived;

    port.Open();


    //Fin Bluetooth



    //Début Vérification

    if (Avertissement >= Exces)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Impossible");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

    }

    else
    {

        if (Consommer < Avertissement)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Vert");
            Console.WriteLine(data + " Kw/H");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
        else
        {
            if (Consommer >= Exces)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Rouge");
                Console.WriteLine(data + "Kw/H");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Jaune");
                Console.WriteLine(data + "Kw/H");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            }

            // Fin Vérification


        }
    }



}
private static void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{


    SerialPort port;
    string data = string.Empty;

    port = (SerialPort)sender;

    data = port.ReadExisting();

    int Consommer = int.Parse(data);

}
}
```

Comment: Always post the code snippets you're working with. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry for french in the code

Comment: That looks great to me, and it's not like you ever need to search for the specific device name or anything since you know it's on COM4. Yeah so you go red if it exceeds the kW hours and otherwise yellow (my French is not that good lol). Sounds like you have a really cool project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am not entirely sure what you want to do on the Arduino side and also because there are many ways to send the data, I will explain the C# serial-port side to you. The easiest way to communicate with an Arduino is probably over an RS-232 port (or maybe in your case serial-port Bluetooth adapter dongle).

First, you'd want to open up a serial-port to communicate with your Arduino over RS-232 which the Arduino boards should have built in. I've gone ahead and wrote a simple program to read data from a serial port below...

```
/// <summary>
/// Read data from Arduino until user presses key.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args">Arguments to the program (we do not take any).</param>
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SerialPort port;

    // first, create a new serial-port
    port = new SerialPort();

    // configure the settings to match the Arduino board
    // below i've just used some of the most common settings
    // to get the point across
    port.BaudRate = 9600;
    port.DataBits = 8;
    port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    port.Parity = Parity.None;

    // you'll have to figure out what your actual COM name is
    // for this example I'll just use COM 11
    port.PortName = "COM11";

    // subscribe to when the data is coming from the port
    port.DataReceived += Port_DataReceived;

    // open up communications with the port
    port.Open();

    // continue to receive data until user presses key
    Console.ReadKey();

    // close access to the port when finished
    port.Close();
}
```

The other thing you'll need to do is create the subscriber (the method that actually prints the data). I've done that for you below...

```
/// <summary>
/// Methods for handling the incoming data from Arduino.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The port that's getting data from Arduino.</param>
/// <param name="e">When the new data comes in.</param>
private static void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort port;
    string data = string.Empty;

    // get a reference to the port that's sending the data
    port = (SerialPort)sender;

    // read the data from the port
    data = port.ReadExisting();

    // print Arduino data to the screen
    Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Snoopy !  If i understand well, i should put that code in my program, but, i use a arduino uno with the bluetooth module (don't remember the name) and a laptop integrated bluetooth (hp elitebook laptop). So wath should i change in the code you gave ?

Comment: @Mazeo If you go the route of using serial ports, you'll have to query each one. So you'll need to write a `for` loop that gets a string from each serial port device. When the device responds with "I'm the Arduino" you'll know that you're at the right COM port.

Comment: @Mazeo Make sure that your Arduino has some sort of command/response mechanism... When you transmit to the Arduino: "Hello, who are you?" ... it will respond with... "Hi there, I'm the Arduino!"... That way you'll know which port it's attached to.

Comment: @Mazeo If there's anything else I can clarify let me know, or feel free to start a chat!

Comment: i'm about to add this code to my program, i'll let you know if i have a problem.

Comment: @Mazeo If you do, just start a chat because  these comments are getting too long.

Comment: I would like but i dont have the privileges.

Comment: @Mazeo Leave a comment down here then and I'll respond and we'll go from there. I can help anything with the C# communication to the Arduino.

Comment: check the question, i uploaded the code